# JQuery Address Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am using jQuery Address Plugin and I have the following code.

```
$.address.change(function(e) {
    if (e.value == "/") {
        $.address.value("/Login.html");                
    }
    else {
        $('#holder').load(e.value);    
    }
});

$('a').address(function() {  
    return $(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, '');  
});
```

The problem is that the **change** event always executes the **else** block whether the page is changed or not. It was working perfect before this day.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved the problem using JQuery Address Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Check what e.value is, and why it is suddenly different than "/".

Comment: When the page is first loaded, it's "/" and when on any page it's "/page.html". So on main page say "Index.html" it should go to "Login.html" and when it has come over "Login.html", it should stop.

Comment: Then try replacing `e.value == "/"` by `/^\/(index\.html)?$/i.test(e.value)` so this will work if e.value == "/" or e.value == "/index.html"

Comment: But I don't need this. e.value is always "/" if it's "/" or "Index.html"